# Find and delete values in db

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I find the SQL Server database, all records where a column (which I do not know the name) that contains the value 'aaa' and 'bbb' ??. I would remove these values from this column. Do not remove the column, values only.

Answer (score 1):

This will be OK for limited use...

```
SELECT 'Starting'
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET
       myValue1 = CASE
                    WHEN @columname = 'myValue1'
                    THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(myValue1, 'bbb', ''), 'aaa', '')
                    ELSE myValue1 
                  END,
       myValue2 = CASE
                    WHEN @columname = 'myValue2'
                    THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(myValue2, 'bbb', ''), 'aaa', '')
                    ELSE myValue2 
                  END,
       myValue3 = CASE
                    WHEN @columname = 'myValue3'
                    THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(myValue3, 'bbb', ''), 'aaa', '')
                    ELSE myValue3 
                  END,
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need to write a T-SQL block (or procedure) which accepts the column argument as a varchar and creates a dynamic Update (or delete) SQL statement which you will need to exuecte via sp_executesql.

```
sp_executesql('Update MyTable Set ' + @Your_column + ' = <the logic goes here>');
```

As an alternate you can query the metadata and get all the columns of the said table in the cursor, then you can loop through the cursor and exuecte the above statement to clean up the table.

```
Select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME='MyTable';
```

In either of the above case, you will have to use a T-SQL block to achieve this objective.